# Generate unique ID for all controls in Winform Application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls, unique

We have a winform application. Recently, I have receive a requirement to must provice to users can save theirs view layout. Like the columns order, column width... in gridview...
I decided store these infor to database, for each user login.
For general, I want to save the layout of all controls in application, so, the first, I must distinguished every controls. I am thinking abount generate unique ID for each control
How can I do this ?

Comment: try using GUID as unique id

Comment: Hi Bychenko, this solution must modify code in every control initiation ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Guid for generating Unique Id.

```
var gid = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Comment: So, I must goto every control declaration and assign GUID, and then I must store this dynamic GUID to database ?,how about this GUID when restart application ? it is same as stored in database. this solution need modify many code.

Comment: guid is not remain same it will regenrated if your application restart.